# Run-time error 1004 Paste special error. What is another way of writing it

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error

```
Workbooks.Open Filename:="W:\MANUFACTURING\lppo\Emerging Markets\98-CMMS Forecast Reports\S2 - Ocean Containers Shipped\Data Files\UtilizationByLocation.xlsx"


ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="RecordCount", RefersToR1C1:="=Q_50_UtilizationByLocation_01_O!R1C100"

Range("CV1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTA(C[-99])"

RecordCount = Range("RecordCount")




Range("A2:G" & RecordCount).Select

'Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select

Selection.Copy

Windows("TC Containers Shipped Report Template.xlsm").Activate
      
Sheets("Utilization By Location").Select

Range("A2").Select

Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
    False, Transpose:=False
```

I am getting an error at  Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
False, Transpose:=False

Comment: You are still posting the code you posted last week where `RecordCount` is a range and not a number, therefore you are not copying anything valid and paste special won’t work.

Comment: I Have about 20 subs in the same module with the same code as above and they all work fine except for this last SUB I am getting an error